# Can you cats using generic method GetType(), and if not, how to handle that?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I am trying to read values from a DataBase driven API called Quickbase. I am also trying to write a very generic method, to handle properties I call from the data base, to set properties in a class called BaseSettings.cs.

I will not always have all of the properties in every table, so will not always know what properties are coming in. For example, one object [TaxForm] may only use 4 of the 19 available properties, and another may use all.

So instead of writing checks for each one, I am doing a query for all fields in the current table, and then finding what available properties I can set using reflection, and the name of the field.

My question is, casting the values of unknown types. How can I do this as a variable, displayed in the method below.

Am I going about it correctly, or should I be using a parameter as the value to be set, and then get the value type from the quickbase call for each property as I pull it down from the tables, and set it to the current object for it.

My example is currently this:

```
 public virtual void SetProperty(string propertyName, object propertyValue)
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        {
            throw new Exception("Property name cannot be null or empty while setting value from quickbase. Make sure yor query to the API is returning a property name! [Filed Title:Label]");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the Type object corresponding to MyClass.
                Type myType = typeof(BaseSetting);
                // Get the PropertyInfo object by passing the property name.
                PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(propertyName);

                if(myPropInfo)
                {
                    this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(this, propertyValue as this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetType();
                }

                // Display the property name.

            }
            catch (NullReferenceException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The property does not exist in our BaseSettings. PLease verify that it exist in the class design, or that the corrct field is being pulled form Quickbase. Error:" + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Where I am setting the new value [could be string, bool, int, ect], is where my question lies. Can I cast using a method as shown below, or not.

```
if(myPropInfo)
{
     this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(this, propertyValue as this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetType());
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what happens when you pass it without casting? and how does `if(myPropInfo)` compile? do you mean `if(myPropInfo != null)` ?

Comment: You need to know the type you are casting to at compile time, but `SetValue(object,object)` doesn't need you to cast otherwise it would be useless.

Comment: I just found it out.  Yea, sorry, the code had a typo. I will post what I did.

Comment: Oh, I never really used object like this. I see what you mean. Thanks, I just learned two things then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did. I am new to generics, and casted the method as the type.

```
 public virtual void SetProperty(string propertyName, object propertyValue)
    {

        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        {
            throw new Exception("Property name cannot be null or empty while setting value from quickbase. Make sure yor query to the API is returning a property name! [Filed Title:Label]");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the Type object corresponding to MyClass.
                Type myType = typeof(BaseSetting);
                // Get the PropertyInfo object by passing the property name.
                PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(propertyName);

                if (myPropInfo != null)
                {
                    this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(this, propertyValue);
                }


            }
            catch (NullReferenceException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The property does not exist in our BaseSettings. PLease verify that it exist in the class design, or that the corrct field is being pulled form Quickbase. Error:" + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```